# all tabs clickable not only text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to make all tab clickable..not only the text.

Any ideas what i am missing?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zv7x46xg/)

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul class="tabCursos">
    <li class="menuCursos"><a href="#tabs-1">test</a></li>
    <li class="menuCursos"><a href="#tabs-2">test2</a></li>
    <li class="menuCursos"><a href="#tabs-3">test3</a></li>
    <li class="menuCursos"><a href="#tabs-4">test4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tabOpen" id="tabs-1">
    test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 
</div>
<div class="tabOpen" id="tabs-2">
    test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 
</div>
<div class="tabOpen" id="tabs-3">
    test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 
</div>
<div class="tabOpen" id="tabs-4">
    test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the padding on the links themselves:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r1nLL5aL/2/

```
#tabs li a{
padding: 10px 80px 20px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to give the links padding.... like

```
.tab_button{
  padding:50px!important;
}
    <li class="menuCursos"><a href="#tabs-1" class="tab_button">test</a></li>
    <li class="menuCursos"><a href="#tabs-2" class="tab_button">test2</a></li>
    <li class="menuCursos"><a href="#tabs-3" class="tab_button">test3</a></li>
    <li class="menuCursos"><a href="#tabs-4" class="tab_button">test4</a></li>
```

This will puff up the clickable zone for the text and make it seem like the tabs are clickable.
Or if you don't want to add classes:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  padding-right:50px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resize your anchors...

```
a.ui-tabs-anchor {
    width: 100%;
    padding: .5em 0 .5em 1em;
    text-align: left;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use builtin UI class on your link `ui-tabs-anchor` and customize by overriding the width and height of  class. OR copy the class code and change according to your requirements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zv7x46xg/4/)